# Regex to find string after certain identifier?

Tags: regex

regex is a mysterium to me, I hope you can help.

What I got:

```
{"_id":"5ba9566baebe0b967536832a","name":"My Name","index":2,"key":"my-name"}
```

What I want:

```
My Name
```

The number and order of attributes can vary, so what I need is basically the string inside the double quotes after *name*.

Can someone please help me with a RegEx one-liner?

It would be great if it can be explained also, so a regex-newbie like me can understand it.

thank you in advance!

Comment: i tried
"(name)":"((\\"|[^"])*)" but this returns the attribute "name" and not the attribute's value

Comment: what is your regex language?

Comment: You should use a JSON parser if you can. A simple regex for this would be `"name":"([^"]*)"` though.

Comment: thank you, this works. unfortunately i rely on some integrated check and must use regex to parse this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

`"name"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"`

It gets anything (except for double quotes) within the double quotes following a `"name"` field.

---

**Here's a working example:**

https://rubular.com/r/LDwRUoljAygS91

Comment: thank you, this also works, although Ahmed's version is shorter :)

Comment: @mrt I just tried to account for potential spaces before/after the colon (`:`) - if you're 100% sure there will be no spaces whatsoever, you may obviously omit this part. ;-)

Comment: ah ok, thank you.
How can I use this the other way round, say, i know "My Name" and want to recognize it, if its in the name? thank you

Comment: ah ok, I guess i made it: "name":"([^"]*My Name')"